# Can't Disable Display Name in URL

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have display name in URL disabled:

```xml
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="never" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
  </providers>
</linkManager>
```

But I can still browse to the display name. I have no custom ItemResolver. I can't figure out why I can browse to these pages by display name.

Comment: Is it generating URLs with display name or can you browse to the display name URL only if you type it in directly?

Comment: If I browse to it. The link manager is not generating the display name url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `LinkProvider` which is responsible for url generation. It has nothing to do with browsing to the url.

For browsing the url you would need to write your own `ItemResolver`.

Default Sitecore `ItemResolver` class has a method which tries to resolve item based on its display name and there is no setting which would allow you to disable it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are just setting the Link Provider to not use `Display Names` when generating the links.

Sitecores Link Provider and Item Resolver use different code. In the item resolver, if the item cannot be resolved by the direct path it calls this code:

```
Item obj2 = this.ResolveUsingDisplayName(args);
```

So it will also resolve by the display name.

To change that you would need to override the `ItemResovler` and remove that line of code.